# Testing an Oracle database for common bugs/performance issues?

Tags: oracle, testing

Are there any good scripts that I could run against my Oracle database to test for SQL defects or maybe common performance issues?

**Edit:** Everything in an Oracle database can be queried. From the PL/SQL packages, indexes and sql running stats. The performance books say look in this place and it will show some absolute values that need the developer to be able to interpret. Has anyone combined their knowledge to include this interpretation within the scripts?

Comment: SQL Errors?  Like bad queries in an application?  Or missing tables from the application's schema?  What kind of SQL errors are you concerned about?

Comment: I'm not looking for defects that raise errors. I'm looking for defects in logic (or defects that have been caused by lack of DB knowledge.) so things that cause bad performance.

Comment: "Defects in Logic"?  What does that mean?  Database design?  Application programs?  How can you spot a defect in logic without having a complete unit test suite?  Are you trying to find some "generic" test that will magically reveal poor performance?

Comment: Please update your question.  Please do not add comments to your question.  Please clarify it to make it complete.

Comment: If there were any scripts someone could write that would find common defects or performance issues, Oracle would probably build it into the database. Oh wait, they have - the PL/SQL compiler warnings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for the information in this book?

[http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-Database-Performance-Techniques-Osborne/dp/0072263059/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264619796&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072263059)

Are you asking about this wiki?

http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Performance+Tuning

Or are you asking for this vendor information?

http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/performance/index.html

---

Edit.  There is no magical set of queries that you simply run and set the various tuning options.

1. Oracle is very complicated.  Changing a parameter to make one thing fast can make several other things faster or slower.  Or makes makes the instance consume more real memory than you have installed.  It's hard to generalize this into magical queries.  You have tools, but even then, the tools give you tuning options and you may need to run different experiments.
2. Performance is a balance.  You have to strike a balance between physical I/O time and CPU time.  It's not possible to generalize this into a magical query.  Your system may need faster physical I/O (data warehouses, for instance, often need this) because it can't effectively work from cache.  My system may need faster processor time and will have to work in cache to achieve this.
3. Performance is a function of your application.  No magical query of Oracle will reveal a single thing about how your application is designed to work.

Comment: These book contain the essence of performance tuning. Has anyone extracted this information into intelligent queries? Or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Manager and it's associated performance tools are a good place to start looking for queries that are consuming the most resources.  Here you can see the plans generated for your SQL, view traces of long running queries, etc.

If you have a budget, there is [Spotlight by Quest](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-oracle/).  I've only used the trial version, but I found it useful.

Comment: OK, thats a good answer. But even the most shinest new features inof OEM in 11g2 only tend to give top 10 queries. I want to go beyond this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Spotlight. Hope it is more stable than Toad was last time I used it.

Comment: Please bear in mind that "Enterprise Manager and it's associated performance tools" are largely chargeable extras on top of the Enterprise Edition license.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the book [Optimizing Oracle Performance](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005276) and any of Cary Millsap's other writings.  It is a waste of time to think about optimizing every query.  You really need an approach to finding out where your performance bottlenecks are.  His Method R approach is a very good one to read up on.  Also most of Tom Kyte's books go into detail about performance issues.